# Python function similar to combination and permutation

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I have some lists

```
a = [1,2]
b = [A,B]
```

I want to generate a new list of lists similar to the following (I don't remeber the name of this "operation"...)

```
[1,A],[1,B],[2,A],[2,B]
```

Is there a rapid way to achieve this result?

Comment: The operation is called [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Answer (score 2):

Its what that [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is for :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> 
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = ['A','B']
>>> 
>>> list(product(a,b))
[(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B')]
```

And if you want the result to be a nested list you can use `map` function to convert the `tuple`s to list :

```
>>> map(list,product(a,b))
[[1, 'A'], [1, 'B'], [2, 'A'], [2, 'B']]
```